# Android WCF Method Not Allowed

Tags: android, wcf

I have the following code that should insert two fields into a database via a WCF Service but I get a 405 Method Not Allowed error when I test in Eclipse.

The WCF works from both Fiddler and my testing C# web client, I only get the error from Android via my phone, leading me to believe the problem may be in this code!

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.com/myservice.svc/postname?fname=fred&lname=frognoggle");

request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

Log.d("WebInvoke", "Saving : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

Can anyone see what I’m missing!

**Edit**

I'm doing a post in Fiddler and if I post:

```
http://www.mysite.com/myservice.svc/postname?fname=fred&lname=frognoggle
```

It all works fine works.

Cheers,

Mike.

Comment: no, I was not saying you can't do POST this way. I updated this before you made your comment (well probably around the same time). POST should work fine that way (I think, never tried it without setting a body.  Just wondering if it is not setting the content length or something since your are not setting a body. Sorry for the confusion.  I removed the answer because it was voted down but if you want the code let me know and I will repost it.

Comment: Ya can’t vote down code, it’s like a picture and it tells a 1000 words!!! Can you please re post it?  I also think you may be on to something regarding Content-Length although, in fiddler if I don’t add Content-Length I get error 411, oh la la…lol.

Comment: Thanks Mike, hope the code helps.  Also, are you running everything local when it is working?  What web server are you running?

Comment: Thanks Brian, I have it working now. It was due to the way I had written my UriTemplate in the OperationContract in my webservice. Fiddler and C# were happy with it but Android/Java were not. I edited my OperationContract and Fiddler and C# are still happy, and so is my phone now! I would love to write a tutorial on all of this, there is only one good one that I know but it’s far from all you need to know to do something like what I’m doing,

Comment: here is the tutorial: http://fszlin.dymetis.com/post/2010/05/10/Comsuming-WCF-Services-With-Android.aspx but I have no idea where to put it, except on one of my sites, but they’re not a blogs, and I can’t put it up here because everyone just bags out on me!

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: back by request.  The code below is what I am using to make a JSON POST on Android and it is working for me.

You are doing an HTTP POST in your Android code.  Are you doing a POST in fiddler too or are you doing a GET?  The reason I ask is that you are not sending a body with your post, only setting the query string.  I have included my Android code that does a JSON POST to a WCF service.

Hope this helps...

If you post more information I will be glad to help and update answer.

```
    public JSONObject sendPOSTurl(String url, JSONObject data) throws JSONException 
    {  
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response;  

        try 
        {  
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(data.toString());

            httppost.setEntity(se);
            httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();  

            if (entity != null) 
            {  
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();  
                String result = convertStreamToString(instream);  

                instream.close();  
                return new JSONObject(result);  
            }  
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("REST", "Failed to POST data", e);
        }

        return null;  
    }

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) 
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try 
    {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        try 
        {
            is.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I've added an edit above. I can show more code if need be also!

Comment: Hey Brain and thanks for the code, but are you saying you can’t send a number of name value pairs from an Android/Java app to a WCF Service???

Answer (score 0):

```
http://www.mysite.com/myservice.svc/postname?fname=fred&lname=frognoggle
```

the url is looks like a HttpGet

if you want to use HttpPost you should put you param in HttpEntity and you param must be       corresponding Content-type like json